# Views Calc always uses contextual filters of master display

Tags: 7, views

I have many displays in the view.
One of them is a views calc table.
Contextual filters in the master display and in the views calc display are different.
And when contextual filters differs from master views calc doesn't work correctly.
 
Views calc ignoges contextual filters of the current display and shows calculation results using contextual filters of master.

Has enybody noticed this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have just experienced this issue! Your question helped me solve the problem with my View. Of course this isn`t the ideal scenario, but knowing about this issue helped me at least get it working... Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Marcos. I'm glad that my question helped you. But I've found another solution. Might it'll siut you better. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As temporary solution :
I've deleted all contextual filters in the Master display and overrided them in other displays

But then i patched Views Cals module.

Views calc realy always executes "filter criterias" and "contextual filters" from default display.
So before executing view we must set view in a needed display. It's very important!
Here is the patch for it:

http://drupal.org/node/1868900#comment-7026538